# Como ejecutar un jar en diferentes versiones de Java

Tags: java

como es posible ejecutar un jar en diferentes versiones de Java ?.
Por poner un ejemplo muy basico baje un jar-calc (una calculadora) un simple jar y pude ejecutarlo en una pc con winXP java 7 y el mismo jar lo ejecute en un Windows 7 java 8
sin problemas.

Hice un hola mundo con un JOptionPane.showMessageDialog y puedo ejecutarlo 
en un maquina con Java 8.60 pero lo llevo a cualquier otra maquina con java inclusive 8 pero otra release y me tira que el jar esta corrupto.
Si instalo la misma version de Java funciona sin problemas en otra maquina.

Comment: "Que el jar está corrupto" es un error muy raro (a no ser que el jar esté efectivamente corrupto). Por favor pon el mensaje de error *tal como te sale*.

Answer (score 1):

Dependerá mucho la versión con la cual compiles tus archivos .java. Usualmente, en el IDE, cuando creas el proyecto, indicas la versión de JDK que vas a usar. Al parecer, parece que creaste el proyecto jar-calc usando JDK 7 (1.7.x), por lo cual puede ejecutarse tanto con Java 7 o superior, tal como mencionas, Java 8.

Si quieres que tu jar pueda ejecutarse con versiones anteriores, debes asegurarte que al compilar tu archivo se use la versión esperada. Esto lo puedes hacer de múltiples maneras (ejemplos apuntando a Java 6).

1. En el IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, IDEA, etc), deberás asegurarte en las propiedades del proyecto, que apunte a la versión específica de Java p.e. Java 6.
2. Si usas maven, puedes indicar la versión de compilador y de ejecución indicándolo como propiedades en tu pom (fuente: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html):

   ```xml
   <project>
     [...]
     <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
     </properties>
     [...]
   </project>
   ```
3. En gradle, puedes agregar estas líneas en el archivo build.gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin 'java'
   sourceCompatibility = 1.6
   targetCompatibility = 1.6
   ```
4. Ejecutando desde línea de comando, al usar `javac`, puedes indicar la versión anterior (fuente: docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

   ```
   javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 <clases y carpetas a compilar>
   ```